# What is strict MIME type checking?

Tags: microsoft-edge, chromium, mime-types, mime

When running a web site I'm getting the following error in my browser's (Edge in this case) console:

```
   Refused to apply style from 'https://example.com/products/styles.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

I've done various searches and can see solutions posted for various different scenarios that cause this issue, but none of them explain what strict MIME type checking is, or how I determine what the supported MIME types are for various resources. I'm looking for a good general explanation of what *strict MIME checking* is and how it determines which MIME types are acceptable?

Comment: Simply serve it as `text/css` like the spec says.

Comment: @tripleee But suppose that's not an option. What alternatives are there?

Comment: I think just like the [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) says: *Browsers use the MIME type, not the file extension, to determine how to process a URL, so it's important that web servers send the correct MIME type in the response's Content-Type header.* I think that's MIME type checking. And we should use correct MIME types for different resources. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types#important_mime_types_for_web_developers) are some common MIME types for different resources.